# A query that select email based in the user time

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a system that will select the old users that have not logged in for the past 7 days. I have a problem with this query.

The query should select the `a`.`email`, `p`.`name`, `a`.`name`, `b`.`account_id`, and I'll explain.

`a` is `accounts`

`b` is `billing`

`p` is `players`

Should check if the `b`.`account_id` is equal `a`.`id` that can get by `p`.`account_id` and after that should check if the `p`.`lastlogin` is higher or equal than 7 days then should return the query results.

I tried this, but it isn't working:

`` SELECT
    `p`.`name`, 
    `a`.`email`, 
    `a`.`name`, 
    `b`.`account_id` 
    FROM 
        `billing` AS `b` AND `players` AS `p` 
            LEFT JOIN `accounts` AS `a` 
                ON `a`.`id` = `p`.`account_id` AND `a`.`name` = `b`.`account_id`
            WHERE `p`.`lastlogin` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + (7 * 86400)
        AND group_id = 1 
    ORDER BY lastlogin 
        DESC ``

I hope that this is understandable, xD.

Regards,

vankk.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here.

```
WHERE `p`.`lastlogin` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + (7 * 86400)
```

It should be `-`instead of `+`.
Also, why don't you use 2 `JOIN`s?

Comment: Don't know how to use two JOIN never did that, that was the problem.

Comment: I am probably late, but to join to tables you can use
`select fields
from table1
inner join table 2
on table1.field=table2.field`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the DATEDIFF function if you are using SQL

```
where DATEDIFF(d, a.DateValue , DateTimeNow) <7;
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp